# How to search increasing values in MySQL if column value has custom template?

Tags: php, mysql

I have varchar column type. Here is example of column value - `"A - 474, B - 709, C - 397, D - 48"`
If i want to search `EXACT` number everything is ok. I use php and query -

```
$note[$key][0] = "B";
$note[$key][1] = "709";

"SELECT 1 FROM example WHERE column LIKE '%".$note[$key][0]." - ".$note[$key][1]."%"
```

But how can i modify query to search increasing values?
I want something like that:

```
"SELECT 1 FROM example WHERE column LIKE '%".$note[$key][0]." and value >= 50"%"
```

I think `RLIKE` may be the solution. Is that right? Is there performance issues?

Comment: You're on the right track with `RLIKE` but to be honest you should split this data into multiple fields.

Comment: Thanks @jonbaldie. It's a performance issue, it will slow down query? For that reason it's better to make "int" field type and search them separetly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split the value.  I would say that `substring_index()` is the way to go:

```
where column = '$key[0]%' and
      substring_index(column, ' - ', -1) + 0 >= 50
```

Note: you should start using parameterized queries instead of embedding user-supplied values into the query string.

Comment: Thank you @gordon-linoff I use parameterized queries, i don't want sql injection. One more question - using substring_index() would be slower than using separate fields?

Comment: @user2337706 . . . It would definitely be slower.  Separate fields can make use of an index.